# Combine mysql result into 1 row

Tags: php, mysql

[table img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trZfZ.png)

```
SELECT namaline, shift1 FROM semualine WHERE cektelatshift1 <> 'Ontime' UNION
SELECT namaline, shift2 FROM semualine WHERE cektelatshift2 <> 'Ontime' UNION
SELECT namaline, shift3 FROM semualine WHERE cektelatshift3 <> 'Ontime';
```

| **namaline** | **shift1** |
| --- | --- |
| Line 1 | Shift 1 |
| Line 2 | Shift 1 |
| Line 3 | Shift 1 |
| Line 1 | Shift 2 |
| Line 2 | Shift 2 |
| Line 3 | Shift 2 |
| Line 1 | Shift 3 |
| Line 2 | Shift 3 |

I want to combine all this result into 1 cell

myexpectation is

| **1 cell** |
| --- |
| Line 1 Shift 1, Line 2 Shift 1, Line 3 Shift 1, Line 1 Shift 2, Line 1 Shift 1, Line 2 Shift 2, Line 1 Shift 3, Line 2 Shift 3 |

Comment: This should not need UNION in the first place, you are selecting from the same table here. To get it all as the content of "one cell", look into GROUP_CONCAT.

Comment: Providing data instead of images of it helps to get much faster recommendations from the community.it is one of the reasons that you get Downvote

Answer (score 1):

Thank for all the answer.
Sorry, I'm still new here should show my DB and used english. I figure out the close answer.

```
SELECT shift1 AS shift, GROUP_CONCAT(`namaline` SEPARATOR ', ') AS 'line'  
FROM semualine 
WHERE cektelatshift1 <> 'Ontime' 
UNION
SELECT shift2 AS shift, GROUP_CONCAT(`namaline` SEPARATOR ', ') AS 'line'  
FROM semualine 
WHERE cektelatshift2 <> 'Ontime' 
UNION 
SELECT shift3 AS shift, GROUP_CONCAT(`namaline` SEPARATOR ', ') AS 'line'  
FROM semualine 
WHERE cektelatshift3 <> 'Ontime';
```

| **shift** | **line** |
| --- | --- |
| Shift 1 | Line 1, Line 2, Line 3 |
| Shift 2 | Line 1, Line 2, Line 3 |
| Shift 3 | Line 1, Line 2 |

Comment: Technically your query is invalid and is only working because you have ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY disabled. This does not answer the problem stated in your question - `I want to combine all this result into 1 cell`. It also serves as a nice example of why you should normalize your table structure.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the output format you are looking for the following needs to be done

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(namaline, ' ', shift1) from semualine;
```

In GROUP_CONCAT space is needed between columns to have the space in the output as well

Comment: Thanks for the help sir. I found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The repeating pattern `shift1, cektelatshift1, shift2, cektelatshift2, ...` is a good indication of a table that would benefit from being normalized.

Both of these queries provide a result similar to your example (cannot be the same as your example is inconsistent). They differ in whether it is the row or column which is concatenated first.

```
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(
        CONCAT_WS(', ',
            IF(cektelatshift1 <> 'Ontime', CONCAT_WS(' ', namaline, shift1), NULL),
            IF(cektelatshift2 <> 'Ontime', CONCAT_WS(' ', namaline, shift2), NULL),
            IF(cektelatshift3 <> 'Ontime', CONCAT_WS(' ', namaline, shift3), NULL)
        )
        SEPARATOR ', '
    )
FROM semualine
WHERE NOT (cektelatshift1 = 'Ontime' AND cektelatshift2 = 'Ontime' AND cektelatshift3 = 'Ontime');
```

```
SELECT
    CONCAT_WS(', ',
        GROUP_CONCAT(
            IF(cektelatshift1 <> 'Ontime', CONCAT_WS(' ', namaline, shift1), NULL)
            SEPARATOR ', '
        ),
        GROUP_CONCAT(
            IF(cektelatshift2 <> 'Ontime', CONCAT_WS(' ', namaline, shift2), NULL)
            SEPARATOR ', '
        ),
        GROUP_CONCAT(
            IF(cektelatshift3 <> 'Ontime', CONCAT_WS(' ', namaline, shift3), NULL)
            SEPARATOR ', '
        )
    )
FROM semualine
WHERE NOT (cektelatshift1 = 'Ontime' AND cektelatshift2 = 'Ontime' AND cektelatshift3 = 'Ontime');
```

Comment: Thanks for the help sir. I found the solution. Sorry i should post my db